# Jar file containing NetSNMPAction

Tags: eclipse, wsimport

I am running an application that uses classes generated from a WSDL using wsimport. As I've encountered NoClassDefFoundError I've added the appropriate jar files to the Eclipse build.

However I'm stymied now with a missing interface:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netsnmp/NetSNMPAction
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.hasDefaultConstructor(ReflectionNavigator.java:464)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.hasDefaultConstructor(ReflectionNavigator.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:193)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:239)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:69)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:51)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:74)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:77)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:255)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:442)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils$4.run(JAXBUtils.java:832)
at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:130)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils.JAXBContext_newInstance(JAXBUtils.java:829)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils.createJAXBContextValue(JAXBUtils.java:306)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils.getJAXBContext(JAXBUtils.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.factory.MethodMarshallerFactory.isContextPathConstruction(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:210)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.factory.MethodMarshallerFactory.isDocLitWrappedPlus(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:170)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.factory.MethodMarshallerFactory.createDocLitMethodMarshaller(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:123)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.factory.MethodMarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createRequest(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:328)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:159)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:141)
at $Proxy11.getComments(Unknown Source)
at com.parasoft.scc.taskimport.pstsec.TestGetComments.main(TestGetComments.java:18)
```

While I'm looking for the Jar file that implements this interface. I'm more troubled by the number and type of missing classes that the generated code seems to require. One missing class was the Java Python interpreter (which I resolved by adding . I'm wondering if I'm heading into a place I don't want to be and should review my Eclipse project. I'm not sure where to start doing that so I'm asking for some advice on how to keep from going down the road to jar hell.

Update: I've changed from using wsdlimport artifacts to using wsdl2java and it's generated code. It's working but I'd still like some advice for the future.